# How can I hide a Siebel Applet button for a specific set of Views?

Tags: siebel

I would like to hide the Query button in an Applet, but only for a specific set of Views.

Is there a recommended way to do this?  I'm looking for a flexible and easy to configure solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you hide the query button, user will still be able to query using Alt-Q button on the applet. Do you want to prevent this as well ? Then you will have ot hide the button AND disable the query method as well.

In openui, you may be able to hide the query button using javascript. Or you could clone the applet, remove the query button, and show it in those different views. This is how some of us used to do this before OpenUI.

To disable the query, you will have to set CANINVOKE to false using applet user properties or applet scripting.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I need to disable query.  the CanInvoke applet property works. I can get can active view from profile attribute `Me.ActiveViewName` and disable based on it.